# Mouse pointer is lagging in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, mouse, touchpad, cursor

I am a new Linux user and I installed Ubuntu 18.04 in my new HP Zbook studio g5. As soon as I boot up everything is working perfectly, yet once the computer goes on sleep mode and is turned on once again my mouse pointer starts lagging a lot.

I have made sure to install Nvidia drivers for the graphics card (P1000 4GB Graphics), and I feel it is not the issue. I am using the the PC's trackpad and not a USB mouse. Is this related to the track-pad drivers installed? Any suggestions? thanks

Specs: 
HP Zbook studio g5,
Intel Core i7-8750H,
16GB (1x16GB) DDR4 2666 ram,
Nvidia P1000 4GB Graphics

Answer (score 0):

After struggling I did find a partial solution in Libinput's git:

https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput/issues/263

For anyone with the SYNA307B:00 06CB:CD46 Touchpad, you could probably encounter the same issue: After computer is suspended, and the session is resumed the mouse stops being responsive and CPU load increases.

The people in Libinput recommend to type this in terminal each time sessions is resumed after laptop is suspended:

```
sudo rmmod i2c_hid
sudo modprobe i2c_hid
```

At the moment issue is closed since "it has to be fixed in the kernel". Hope it gets fully fixed soon instead of this partial solution.